# How can I get text from <span name="nv" > with BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

I want to get a text from `<span>` tag but I have some
problems

my tag is

`<span name="nv" data-value="28,341,469">$28.34M</span>`

I am writing this code:

```
import requests 
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
response = requests.get(url)
url = "https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?groups=top_100&sort=user_rating,desc"
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,"html.parser")

gross = soup.find("p", class_="sort-num_votes-visible")

gross
```

this is the output, I do not understand how can I have only gross ($28.34M)

```
<p class="sort-num_votes-visible">
<span class="text-muted">Votes:</span>
<span data-value="2350679" name="nv">2,350,679</span>
<span class="ghost">|</span> <span class="text-muted">Gross:</span>
<span data-value="28,341,469" name="nv">$28.34M</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like to use CSS selectors for this. You can use the `select_one` method and target the same `<p>` tag with the `sort-num_votes-visible` class, but then target the next sibling of the span containing the text `Gross:`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?groups=top_100&sort=user_rating,desc"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,"html.parser")

print(soup.select_one('p.sort-num_votes-visible > span:-soup-contains("Gross:") + span'))
```

Output:

```
<span data-value="28,341,469" name="nv">$28.34M</span>
```

You can check out more about the CSS selectors available in BeautifulSoup by reading up in the SoupSieve documentation: https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

you can try `:nth-child(index)`

```
gross = soup.select('.sort-num_votes-visible span:nth-child(5)')

for g in gross:
    print(g.text)
```